# Cannot figure out why do I get GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Tags: c++, opengl

I am creating a small game and I want to take things out of the main loop inside of classes.

I want to draw the figure which is bound to the player.

```
    //identity matrix
    Matrix44 model; 

    //set up the model to world transform
    model.SetTranslation(player.position);

    //pass a uniform which specifies the color of the player to the fragment shader
    glUniform3f(colorLocation, player.color._x, player.color._y, player.color._z);

    //pass the model as well 
    glUniformMatrix4fv(transformLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &model.m[0][0]);

    //draw
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
```

This is the implementation in the main loop. And it works like a charm.
The problem comes when I try call the same functions from a Player class.

```
void Player::drawPlayer(GLint transformLocation, GLint colorLocation)
{   

Matrix44 model;     
model.SetTranslation(position); 

glUniform3f(colorLocation, color._x, color._y, color._z);   
std::cout << glGetError() << std::endl;  <- I get error 1028 here

glUniformMatrix4fv(transformLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &model.m[0][0]);
std::cout << glGetError() << std::endl;   <- I get error 1028 here

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
std::cout << glGetError() << std::endl;

}
```

I am making these calls after I`ve successfully compiled the shader program which renders the rest of the objects int he scene without any problems and after I've set up the VBOs, VAOs etc.

I have implemented a similar class which draws some cubes in order to create the level. (both utilize the same VAO and VBO)

```
 void Level::drawLevelTiles(GLint colorLocation, GLint transformLocation)
```

{
    std::vector::iterator it;

```
for (it = levelTiles.begin(); it != levelTiles.end(); ++it)
{
    Matrix44 model;
    GameObject temp = *it;

    model.SetTranslation(temp.position);
    glUniform3f(colorLocation, temp.color._x, temp.color._y, temp.color._z);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(transformLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &model.m[0][0]);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
}

for (it = fallingBlocks.begin(); it != fallingBlocks.end(); ++it)
{
    Matrix44 model;
    GameObject temp = *it;
    model.SetTranslation(temp.position);

    glUniform3f(colorLocation, temp.color._x, temp.color._y, temp.color._z);        
    glUniformMatrix4fv(transformLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &model.m[0][0]);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
}
```

The above code is literally the same but it works. And both classes inherit from the same base class - GameObject. I can leave it and use a workaround but it doesn't feel right.

This is the whole main loop:

```
  ourShader.Use();

    Matrix44 view;
    Matrix44 projection;        

    projection = projection.CreatePerspective(45.f, width / height, 0.1f, 100.f);       

    Vector3 eye(0.f, 0.f, -3.f);
    Vector3 center(0.f, 0.f, 0.f);
    Vector3 up(0.f, 1.f, 0.f);
    view = view.CreateLookAt(eye, center, up);


    GLint transformLocation = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "model");
    GLint viewLocation = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "view");
    GLint projectionLocation = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "projection");
    GLint colorLocation = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "cubeColor");

    glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &view.m[0][0]);       
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &projection.m[0][0]);       
    //=====================================================================================

    //
    //draw the player
    //player.drawPlayer(colorLocation, transformLocation);

    // draw the level tiles
    glBindVertexArray(level._VAO);
    level.drawLevelTiles(colorLocation, transformLocation);
    player.drawPlayer(colorLocation, transformLocation);

    glBindVertexArray(0);

    // Swap the screen buffers
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
```

Any suggestions would be more than welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the definition and the use of 'drawPlayer`

```
void Player::drawPlayer(GLint transformLocation, GLint colorLocation)
player.drawPlayer(colorLocation, transformLocation);
```

Do you see the parameters mismatch?

Comment: Thank you, sir! This was the issue.